# Django send_mail not working with gmail

Tags: django, email, smtp, gmail

I have been trying everything to get django to send a test email, with no success. My test email is being sent from a python anywhere dev site. Here is my views ajax:

```
def ajaxLearning(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        send_mail('Put your Email subject here', 'Put your Email message here.',
                  'myspamgoes@gmail.com', ['someemail@yahoo.com'],
                  fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponse("end");
     else:
        pass
```

And here is my settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myspamgoes@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'myspamgoes@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myspamgoes@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

At this point I feel as if I am making some higher level mistake such as, using the wrong version of django, failing to install something crucial, or doing something wrong on the gmail side. For the password, which I changed earlier today, I am using the one that I would use to normally sign in to my account. Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Does Django raise an exception?

Comment: Have you set: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I I did have the EMAIL_BACKEND set up at one point. The solution was actually that gmail was blocking access. I had to go into my gmail account to and flip a switch to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailhere@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'  
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemailhere@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```